# Why a subView won't stay in the parent frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view and inside it there's a `UIImage`. The image isn't static and I can move it around if I drag my finger around (using drag events) The problem is that sometimes the picture moves outside of the `UIView` frame. What's the appropriate way to keep it inside the parent frame bounds?

--UIViewA

--------UIViewB

--------------UIImage

--------------UIButton

I want to keep UIImage inside UIViewB

```
- (IBAction)myButtonSingleTap:(UIButton *)sender {
    imDragging = YES;
    [_myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

}

- (IBAction)myButtonDragInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [_myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(draging:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

}
- (void)dragBegan:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {

    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    startingTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}
- (void)draging:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _movingPic.frame = CGRectMake(currentTouchPoint.x, currentTouchPoint.y, 28, 23);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code / event handlers you use to move the image around?

Comment: clipToBounds = YES will just stop the image from displaying when it goes outside the view. It won't stop the image from going outside the view in the first place.

Comment: before setting frame check it using CGRectContainsRect(<#CGRect rect1#>, <#CGRect rect2#>) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check the location of the view during the dragging.

At some point you will be setting the frame of the image depending on the user's drag direction, etc...

During this you should have a logic check like...

```
If new location x value is less than 0 then set new location x = 0.
If new location x value plus image width is greater than view width then set new location x = view width - image width.
```

etc...

Then use the new location as the point to move the image to.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but hoped that there's a more elegant way doing that that depends on the parent frame.

Comment: Hmm... you could possibly use AutoLayout constraints to move the view but always make sure the constraints lie within the parent view. (Ooh, I actually think that would be possible and quite elegant).

Comment: I'm targeting my app to iOS 5 and above so autolayout is out of the question. Sounds like a nifty solution though.

Comment: Ah, yeah, no AutoLayout on iOS 5. :(

Comment: Your solution was the closest to what I had in mind so the check goes to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the touch recogniser to the parent view and not the entire view

Comment: I'm not using touch recognisers. I'm using something like `- (IBAction)myButtonDragInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [_myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(draging:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    
}` and myButton is inside the child view

Comment: What's the frame and parent view of _myButton?

Comment: currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
Not self.view, but the parent view of the image

Comment: Tries that, the starting would sync on 0,0, but when I drag the pic still goes out of bounds.

Comment: startingTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
Change this as well

Comment: I changed all the `touch locationIn` , still no go

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the new frame, make sure it is contained by the moving view's superview's bounds.

```
- (void)draging:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev
{
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(currentTouchPoint.x, currentTouchPoint.y, 28, 23);
    newFrame.x = MAX(newFrame.x, 0);
    newFrame.y = MAX(newFrame.y, 0);
    newFrame.x = MIN(newFrame.x, _movingPic.superview.bounds.size.width - 28);
    newFrame.y = MIN(newFrame.y, _movingPic.superview.bounds.size.height - 23);
    _movingPic.frame = newFrame;
}
```