# UIImageView with sticker and adding Gesture on Sticker

Tags: swift, uiimageview, gesture

I have one ImageView and sticker on it now I want to add Gesture on that sticker, Everything is working properly but ,my sticker is going out from UIImageView's layer as shown in Image. I want sticker's gesture within ImageView's Boundaries only.

[image]

Following is my Code:

```
func addStickers(image: UIImage) {

    gesture = "Stickers"

    imgSticker  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80, height: 80))
    imgSticker.center = view.center
    imgSticker.image = image
    imgSticker.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    imgSticker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.view.addSubview(imgSticker)
    //imgImage.addSubview(imgSticker)

    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    panGesture.delegate = self

    pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchGesture(_:)))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self

    rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotateGesture(_:)))
    rotateGesture.delegate = self

    imgSticker.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    imgSticker.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    imgSticker.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
}
```

I am calling this function and my handle methods as below:

```
                addStickers(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sticker1.png"))
```

func handlePanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

```
    if gesture == "Stickers" {
        let recognizerCenter = recognizer.location(in: self .view)
        imgSticker.center = recognizerCenter

    } else {
        let recognizerCenter = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
        txtLabel.center = recognizerCenter
    }

}

func handlePinchGesture(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture == "Stickers" {
         imgSticker.transform = imgSticker.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
         recognizer.scale = 1.0

    } else {
        txtLabel.transform = txtLabel.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1.0
    }

}

func handleRotateGesture(_ recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

    if gesture == "Stickers" {
         imgSticker.transform = imgSticker.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
         recognizer.rotation = 0.0

    } else {
        txtLabel.transform = txtLabel.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
        recognizer.rotation = 0.0
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm currently tackling the same issue. Not much time spent on it so far, but here's a potentially helpful link - the trick is to *write* the code to keep it in the bounds you want it to stay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460229/why-a-subview-wont-stay-in-the-parent-frame#16460566 (It seems the example codes - yes, plural - all behave like this too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing **self.view** in `self.view.addSubview(imgSticker)` to the ImageView of your image that is being edited, the one you put stickers onto it. Hope it helps.

So, it should be like this - `imageView.addSubview(stickerOnImg)`. I had same issue before and this worked for me.